# Why I always have conflicts when I "Get Latest" using TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Why is it that when I "Get Latest" using TFS I always get merge conflicts, regardless if I have changed any files or not (it seems)?

For example, I have 2 Visual Studios (**2017**) opened, one has a project that I work on and the other is another project that the first project uses. The issue happens in my second VS, every time I get latest it always produces conflicts. The thing is I never change any files in my second Visual Studio project. How this is possible?

I have tried `tf scorch` which did not help at all.

I am not sure if it helps but this is the remote project hierarchy:

```
Apps
 - The project I work on
 - The second project that produces conflicts
 - many more projects
```

I map the whole "Apps" directory

**Note**: that would not be a problem normally as I would do Control + A and then "Override local files" for all of the conflicts. However, I recently had to remap the remote project folder which produced 49K conflicts after the mapping process finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by creating a new Workspace and mapping the remote project folder again (e.g. "Apps"). That seemed to have solved the issue